# Visual Studio 2017 fails to deploy UWP apps to IoT device

Tags: windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

Visual Studio (VS 2017) has started failing to deploy to my IoT device ... I recently started using a more recent version of Windows 10 IoT Core (upgraded from [build 17134](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/currentcommercial) to [insider build 17692](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot)) and Visual Studio can no longer deploy UWP apps.

The reported error is:

> DEP6957: Failed to connect to device [IP Address] using Universal
>   Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode
>   is specified in the project debug settings. COMException - Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x801C0003

The IP address is valid and VS can see the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an error reflecting a mismatch between the Windows SDK installed on the Visual Studio machine and the OS version on the IoT device.

For recent versions of Windows 10 IoT Core (I'm using the insider images that you can install through the Windows IoT Dashboard), a recent version of the Windows SDK  (I used [Windows 10 SDK 1803](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)) must be installed on your deployment machine.

Comment: Thank you for contributing your experience.It will be helpful for somebody who encounter this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also uninstalled and reinstalled UWP parts of VS as described above.

Finally, I clicked on "update" for the whole VS installation (Visual Studio Installation program). Drew 4GB out of the net over night and in the morning everything was working as it should...

Comment: From Review: This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.